# Publish project with Data and Business class Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to publish my project to put it in a free host, but I don't know how to publish with the Data and Business layers, I try different videos and tutorials but no one have this objects

[This is the image of my proyect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67pku.png)
[image]

Comment: If the main project has project references to Business and Data then you only need to publish the main project. The other two will have their assemblies copied when you publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to publish only ClusterMinero the business and data assemblies will automatically added to the reference.